# Помогите мне понять из за чего не работает js код

Tags: javascript

Я полный новичок в js, так что не судите строго.

Я попытался сделать калькулятор, но почему то он не работает.

```js
alert("Вы зашли в онлайн калькулятор");

var moove = prompt("Выберите какое действие вы хотите сделать \n1.Прибавление \n2.Вычитание \n3.Умножения \n4.Деление")

var num1 = prompt("Введите 1 число");
var num2 = prompt("Введите 2 число");

if (typeof num1 && num 2 == NuN) {
  alert("Вы ничего не ввели");
  break;
}

num1 = parseInt(num1);
num2 = parseInt(num2);

if (moove == 1) {
  answer = num1 + num2
}

if (moove == 2) {
  answer = num1 - num2
}

if (moove == 3) {
  answer = num1 * num2
}

if (moove == 4) {
  answer = num1 / num2
}

alert("Ответ: " + answer);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if (typeof num1 && num 2 ==NuN){` - это что?

```
if (!isNaN(num1) || !isNaN(num2)) {
  alert("Вы ничего не ввели");
  //break;
} else {
  ...
}
```

Comment: если я верно помню, то `break` в блоке `if` также недопустим

Comment: @letUser Да, помните правильно.

Answer (score 0):

```js
alert("Вы зашли в онлайн калькулятор");

var moove = prompt("Выберите какое действие вы хотите сделать \n1.Прибавление \n2.Вычитание \n3.Умножения \n4.Деление")

var num1 = prompt("Введите 1 число");
var num2 = prompt("Введите 2 число");

num1 = parseInt(num1);
num2 = parseInt(num2);

if (isNaN(num1) || isNaN(num2)) {

  alert("Вы ничего не ввели");
} else {



  if (moove == 1) {
    answer = num1 + num2
  }

  if (moove == 2) {
    answer = num1 - num2
  }

  if (moove == 3) {
    answer = num1 * num2
  }

  if (moove == 4) {
    answer = num1 / num2
  }

  alert("Ответ: " + answer);
}
```

Comment: Э... Возможно, я чего-то не понимаю, но зачем `parseInt`'ы помещены внутри `if`?

Comment: А как же числа с запятой?)